What distribution does the likelihood follow?
Consider a standard Gaussian distribution ($\mu=0$, $\sigma=1$), from which you sample $N=1000$ times.
If you were to obtain the likelihood of the distribution parameters mu and sigma for each of the N samples, is there a certain distribution that the likelihood would follow? My assumption is that this distribution would be some sort of function of mu and sigma.
I've attempted to simulate this and the resulting histplot looks a bit like a $\chi^{2}$ distribution for $k=1$...

For $\ N\ $ independent samples $\ X_1,X_2,\dots,X_N\ $ from a normal distribution $\ \mathcal{N}\big(\mu,\sigma^2\big)\ ,$ the likelihood function $\ L\ $ is given by
$$
L\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\frac{1}{\big(\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}\big)^N}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_\limits{i=1}^N\left(\frac{X_i-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}\ .
$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
L\le x&\Leftrightarrow\\
\ln x+N\ln\big(\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}\big)&\ge\ln\big(\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}\big)^NL=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_\limits{i=1}^N\left(\frac{X_i-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\ ,
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
P(L\le x)&=P\left(\sum_\limits{i=1}^N\left(\frac{X_i-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\ge-2\ln x-2N\ln\big(\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}\big)\right)\\
&=1-\chi^2_N\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+N\ln\left(\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}\right)\right)\ ,
\end{align}
because $\ \frac{X_i-\mu}{\sigma}\ $ are independent standard normal variates for $\ i=1,2,\dots,N\ ,$ so the sum of their squares follows a chi-squared distribution with $\ N\ $ degrees of freedom.
